# Assembly branch instruction, bne- 0b

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, powerpc

Taken from Google Protobuf PowerPC GCC, there are methods for 32 bit architecture, but none for 64 bit.

I see the `0:` flag, and later a `bne- 0b` branch if not equal to a flag before current address.

What does the `-` do in the `bne-` statement?

Specifically, when I write a version of this for 64 bit, I get syntax errors if I use `0:` and `bne- 0b`, but the 32 bit version works just fine.

Why does it accept a word as a flag, but not `0:`?

Below is the [Protobuf 32 bit method.](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/860bd12fec5c69e6529565165532b3d5108a7d97/src/google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_ppc_gcc.h#L65)

```
inline Atomic32 NoBarrier_AtomicIncrement(volatile Atomic32 *ptr,
                                          Atomic32 increment) {
  Atomic32 temp;

  __asm__ __volatile__(
      "0:                                  \n\t" // flag
      "lwarx %[temp],0,%[ptr]              \n\t"
      "add %[temp],%[increment],%[temp]    \n\t"
      "stwcx. %[temp],0,%[ptr]             \n\t"
      "bne- 0b                             \n\t" // branch not equal <dash> flag before
      : [temp] "=&r"(temp)
      : [increment] "r"(increment), [ptr] "r"(ptr)
      : "cc", "memory");

  return temp;
}
```

Below is my attempt at a 64 bit version.

```
inline Atomic64 NoBarrier_AtomicIncrement(volatile Atomic64 *ptr,
                                          Atomic64 increment) {
  Atomic64 temp;

  __asm__ __volatile__(
      "0:                                  \n\t"
      "ldarx %[temp],0,%[ptr]              \n\t"
      "add %[temp],%[increment],%[temp]    \n\t"
      "stdcx. %[temp],0,%[ptr]             \n\t"
      "bne- 0b                             \n\t"
      : [temp] "=&r"(temp)
      : [increment] "r"(increment), [ptr] "r"(ptr)
      : "cc", "memory");

  return temp;
}
```

Note that `Atomic32` is an `int`, and `Atomic64` is a `long`.

Also, if I replace the `0:` flag by a word, such as `loopai64:`, I don't get errors. However, when I run the compiler, it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Check your PowerPC manual. It is a static branch prediction hint

Comment: Awesome, that answers the `bne- ` question.

Answer (score 1):

The `0:` is a local label. However, directional branch, such as `bne- 0b` (`0b` means jump to first instance of label `0` that is above current location) are not supported on all architectures.

In the end, I solved the issue by using longer label names.

Comment: Terminology: `0:` is a (local) *label*.  "flag" means something else in asm.